# In Power BI, how to remove rows having names starting with 'NewHire' & count remaining employees?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

My table looks like this example:

[image]

I want to remove all rows which start with 'NewHire' as name and calculate the number of employees remaining. The list will have more NewHires added later, hence I want to write a code to automate the process in Power BI.

Please help me.

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in **Power Query Editor**. Go to the table and select your column. From top right corner drop down, select **Text Filter** and the select **Does not begin with...** and put **NewHire** in the respected filtering text box.

Follow this below image as a reference.

[image]